# Moment Generating Function Question - Interpretting what f(0) means

Tags: statistics

I have the following moment generating function:

$$M(t) = 1/32 + (5/32)e^t + (5/16)e^{2t} \\+ (5/16)e^{3t} + (5/32)e^{4t} + (5/32)e^{5t}$$

And I am asked to solve for $f(0)=P(Y=0),$ as $Y$ is the discrete random variable. I am aware of how to solve for the mean and variance of $Y$ using $M'(0)$ and $M''(0),$ but what would I use for just $P(Y=0)?$ The original function given? Thank you.

Comment: Is the final term $\frac 5{32}e^{5t}$ or $\frac 1{32}e^{5t}$? If the latter, I suggest you factorise $M(t)$ to something easier to handle

Comment: Your first assumption was correct (not the latter)

Comment: @Henry, I apologize. I was mistaken, it was the latter of what you had mentioned.

Comment: I edited your question, mainly by putting in `$`-signs and `{}`s. My intention was not to change it. If you want to change the last term, please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $Y$ is clearly non-negative. $e^{tY} \to 0$ as $ t\to -\infty$ if $Y >0$ and $e^{tY} \to 1$ as $ t\to -\infty$ if $Y=0$. Hence $P(Y=0) =\lim_{t \to -\infty} Ee^{tY}$ which is $\frac 1 {32}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For a discrete random variable, you have the probability generating function $$G(z) = E\left[z^X\right]$$ and this  implies that $$G(e^t) = E\left[e^{tX}\right] = M_X(t)$$ so write your moment generating function in terms of $e^t$, for example using $e^{3t}=\left(e^t\right)^3$, then find the probability generating function and calculate  $G(0)$